# How to hide, pre-set and disable a select tag

Tags: php, css

How to hidden the select option tag . When I try to put hidden in select I can still see it in my php page don't know why ? input tag is easy to hidden but the select option is difficult to hide

```
<select  type="hidden" style="text-color:white;"name="syearid" class="select2_group form-control"  style="text-align:center;" >

              <?php
                $YearNow=Date('Y');
                        include('../connection/connect.php');
                        $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM school_year");
                        $result->bindParam(':syearid', $res);
                        $result->execute();
                            for ($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++) {
                                $isSelected = (($YearNow=Date('Y') == $row['from_year']) ? " selected" : "");
                                echo "<option style='text-color:white;' value='".$row['syearid']."'$isSelected>".$row['from_year'].'-'.$row['to_year']."</option>";
                                                        }   
                                ?>

                                </select>
```

Comment: Firstly, you're not doing anything with `bindParam(':syearid'`

Comment: Wouldn't this be a `css` question? Where the answer would be `display: none;`... or `visibility:hidden`... or a number of options. There is no `type` attribute for a `select`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<select name="syearid" class="select2_group form-control"  style="text-align:center;text-color:white;display:none;" >
```

`display:none;` will hide the select tag.

Note that you can also do this (better):

```
<style>
    #syearid{text-align:center;text-color:white;display:none;}
</style>
<select id="syearid" name="syearid" class="select2_group form-control" >
```

---

To pre-set the value, and disable the control, you can do this:

```
<select disabled>
  <option>Car</option>
  <option selected>Bus</option>
  <option>Van</option>
</select>
```

[jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gthbswhe/)